# JavaFX: handle key combination and mouse event simultaneously

Tags: java, events, javafx, key, mouse

I need to react on a key + mouse event combination like:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + `left_mousebutton_clicked`

But I can't figure out, how to handle the "left_mousebutton_clicked" only if the key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> occurs.

A solution like

```
if(MouseEvent.isControlDown())
```

will not work cause there may be different key combinations with any kind of the letters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Both ctrl and shift can be done the way you aproached it there. The left mouse key is the `PrimaryButton`

```
if(mouseEvent.isControlDown() && mouseEvent.isShiftDown && mouseEvent.isPrimaryKeyDown){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

And for the "non special" key (like r) I thnk you need to make a global boolean - and a seperate keyevent listener for it. So:

```
boolean rIsDown = false;

scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.R){
    System.out.println("r was pressed");
    //set your global boolean "rIsDown" to true
}
});

scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.R){
    System.out.println("r was released");
    //set it rIsDown back to false
}
});
```

Then use your it together with the other conditions...

```
    if(mouseEvent.isControlDown() && mouseEvent.isShiftDown && rIsDown &&  mouseEvent.isPrimaryKeyDown){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a container to store the currently pressed keys:

```
private final Set<KeyCode> pressedKeys = new HashSet<>();
```

You can attach listeners to the `Scene` of the control the you want to target with the mouse-click:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> pressedKeys.add(e.getCode()));
scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> pressedKeys.remove(e.getCode()));
```

While these listeners maintain the set, you can simply attach a listener on the target `Node`:

```
Label targetLabel = new Label("Target Label");
targetLabel.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY &&
        pressedKeys.contains(KeyCode.R) && 
        e.isShortcutDown() &&
        e.isShiftDown()) 

        System.out.println("handled!");
});
```

*Example `Application`:*

```
public class MouseClickExample extends Application {

    private final Set<KeyCode> pressedKeys = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 250);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> pressedKeys.add(e.getCode()));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> pressedKeys.remove(e.getCode()));

        Label targetLabel = new Label("Target Label");
        targetLabel.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && pressedKeys.contains(KeyCode.R) && e.isShortcutDown() && e.isShiftDown())
                System.out.println("handled!");
        });

        root.getChildren().add(targetLabel);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Note: The meta keys are also stored in the `Set` but they are not used by this example. The meta keys could be also checked in the set rather than using methods on the mouse-event.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I thought about a similar solution to store a boolean if all needed keys  where handled and to compare this with the mouseclick event. But I assumed there is a native (build in) javafx function especially for shortcut + mouseevents. But anyway your way with the 'set' seems realy elegant.